# AD Thresh, possible or not?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have seen some people playing AD thresh and I have always played him more tanky. Is AD thresh a viable build?

Comment: Are you asking possible or viable? Sure it's possible since he's ranged.  Viable, no. I'll be one of the first to say most things are viable but most definitely not AD Thresh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote this in comments, but I feel the need to post this as an answer, and I recognize the fact this will be downvoted by most people who do not play competitively.

**DISCLAIMER:** If you want to play around with AD thresh in normals, go right on ahead.  If you do so in ranked, people who take this game seriously **WILL** report you for this type of behavior.  Take this from someone who was banned in S1 for running **Karthus Jungle**, even though I am a Gold tier player and was actually winning games with it.  You can get banned for picking certain champions in un-orthodox roles.

Your title is : **AD Thresh, possible or not?**

***Possible***?  Yeah, sure, anything is possible.  I can play karma as a solo-top if I feel like it.

However in your question, you ask : **Is AD thresh a viable build?**

***Viable***?  **Absolutely not**.

What makes an AD Carry, then?

> High AD base stats : *(Thresh does not have this)*.

***Example:***    **Caitlynn's** or **MF's** attack damage goes up 3 per level, **Thresh** is 2.2. Negligeable, however; **Cait** and **MF's** attack speed goes up 3% per level, while **Thresh** only goes up 1%.  **That would mean a fully leveled Thresh will be AA'ing 34% slower than a regular AD.**

```
An attack damage/speed steroid :  *(Thresh does not have this)*.
```

***Example:***  **Ezreal** passive, **Trist** Rapid Fire, MF **Impure Shots**, **Cait** passive, Graves **Quickdraw**, **Varus** passive... I could keep going for days, but you get the idea.

```
A skill that does decent amount of bonus damage.  *(Thresh does not have this)*
```

Not EVERY AD Ranged AD Carry has this, but most do.  ***Examples:***  Graves **Buckshot**, MF **Double Up**, Cait **Piltover Peacemaker**, Ezreal **Mystic Shot**, Ashe **Volley**

```
An Escape/Disengage ability
```

Again, not EVERY AD carry has this, but most do. ***Examples***: Corki **Valkyrie**,  Trist **Rocket Jump**. Ezreal **Arcane Shift**, Graves **Quickdraw**, Cait **.45 Caliber net**

```
A high-damage ultimate ability:   *(Thresh does not have this)*
```

***Examples:***  MF, Ez, Graves, Cait, Corki, Tristana... etc.

`The only thing Thresh has comparable to other AD Carries?`

Ranged on his auto-attacks.  But that ***does not*** make him a viable AD Carry.  If you follow that logic, Sona, Nidalee, Soraka, Karthus, Brand, Annie are all viable AD carries, and they aren't.

Sources : [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki), being Gold S1, S2 and now Div III gold S3.

Comment: I think you should reread the question, it is not "is thresh a viable ad carry" it is "is thresh a viable ad champion" there is a big difference.

Comment: Whether you want to phrase it as "AD Champion" or "AD Carry", those are semantics, and the end result is the same.  Thresh as anything but support in high-elo will net you a warning or a ban, for the reasons I listed in my answer.  You can downvote me all you want, I knew this was coming. Depending on your ELO bracket, your definition and my definition of "viable" can differ greatly.

Comment: Except that AD champion and AD carry are not semantics, there are plenty of AD jungle and AD toughs that do not get played as AD carries for the sole reason that they are not viable as Bot lane champions. If you had read the question properly and actually read my answer correctly you would have understood that. I down voted you for the aggressive and completely unfounded claims you came up with against the answer I provided. This is a quote from my own answer which you clearly missed- "Would I have him as the Attack Damage Carry? No."

Comment: @ravekner Forgive me if pointing out flaws in your answer whilst backing up mine with facts seems "aggressive" to you.  Also, everything I said was factual, while your answer is purely subjective, and backed up with nothing but your own previous experiences.  Unfortunately, this site isn't about "In my opinions" and "It is my beliefs".  This site is about facts, and your answer contains none.  So think twice before saying something is "unfounded", because in this instance, nothing is "unfounded" except your claims.

Comment: Just because I didn't provide some link or source to additional information, my information is automatically incorrect? Your entire argument and answer is based on a question that was NEVER ASKED. THAT is what makes your answer unfounded and aggressive to the point that it is not helpful. If you want to change your answer to actually address the question, then go right ahead, I would even up vote you for it. As it stands, you did not answer the question presented and as such your answer is not useful.

Comment: @Ravekner I'll make it easier for you to understand. Read my answer and replace every instance of the word "carry" with "champion". Taa-Daa! Totally pertinent answer.  As I stated earlier, "champion" and "carry" are inter-changeable in this instance, and your reply to my answer is pure semantics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7563/discussion-between-ravekner-and-marco-leblanc)

Comment: Actually Tresh, has his Death Sentence, which has a passive ability that adds magic damage equal to 200% of his AD at lvl 5... that together with some attackspeed, makes Tresh do some serious damage, not to mention getting armor for picking up souls. Which does make him a nice top ad champ at times.

Comment: Also, just going to point this out, since you are trying to use your rating in Ranked play as some kind of basis for why your answer is correct, Gold III is about half way up the overall ladder. You aren't a pro so stop acting all high and mighty.

Comment: I have to agree with Ravekner. Thresh may not be the best but is a quite valuable top laner. He may not be the AD Carry but he can damn well be an AD Bruiser, thus making him a viable AD champion (so answering the question with: YES). Also, nobody will get banned for picking outside the meta. I can imagine  you'd like to think so but it might have something to do with the attitude like shown above.

Comment: I like to compare this champion with Jarvan. Their kits are simular at a lot of points. And I don't think a gold S3 player is going to tell me Jarvan isn't viable. Thresh isn't discovered yet in solo queue but when playing in a premade team, he can be devastating.

Comment: J4 and Thresh are not similar, at all... J4 is extremely viable top, jungle, even mid.  Anyways, if you guys don't care what works in higher Elos, stop asking.  I'm just relaying what works and doesn't work at 1600+ Elo

Comment: @Joetjah Hehe, I was thinking the same thing, probably not because he ran Jungle Karthus, but probably because of his attitude that he was banned.

Comment: @Marco Leblanc Both an ult which create a circle of walls? Both a gapcloser? Both a knockup? Both a boost (AD from Flag or AP from collected souls)? Both high armor? Jarvan and Thresh are more alike than what you princesses from high ELO think up there.

Comment: @joetjah The difference is in Base stats, and the amount they are increased at level up.  There's a reason Riot slaps the 'Support' tag on some champs, and the 'Bruiser' tag on others.  It's because of these base stats.  If you take a level 18 Thresh and a level 18 J4, with the exact same gear and make them AA each other, J4 will win, with well over ~33% of his HP left when Thresh dies.  They ARE not similar, even though you think they are because of their kits.

Comment: They are similar, not the same. Those are two different words. And your logic makes no sense: so every champion Jarvan will beat at lvl 18 with the same items is not a viable top laner? If you look at LolKing's stats on them both top laning, they don't differ much in statistics. Sure Thresh's win percentage tends to be lower, but that doesn't mean he isn't viable.

Comment: My definition of viable = whatever is currently semi-OP or bordering on broken, like Elise laning phase for instance, or 53% or higher win rates.  Just because you can play a game and manage to not feed doesn't mean it's viable.  Like I've mentioned previously, our definitions of viability may differ greatly.  If Thresh was so 'viable' top lane, he would be played there. Unfortunately for you, it has never happened in any real tournament setting yet, and I have never seen it done either.  And I hate to bust your bubble, but it never will happen in competitive play, either :/

Comment: the point of it all is that thresh has not been in the game long enough for the portion of the player base that plays him to know all the ins and outs, strengths and weaknesses of this champ yet. the fact that you say he cannot be played in any other role beyond support in competitive games is ignorant. just because it hasn't happened yet does not mean that it never will happen.

Comment: also, in what fight outside of two AD carries fighting do you ever see two champs just auto attacking each other??? that is the most ignorant example of why one champ is better than another that you could ever give in a discussion.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Riot also pasted the tag Tank and Ranged on Thresh btw

Comment: @everyone who is arguing with me The only thing worse than a meta-sheep is an anti-meta-sheep.

Comment: I don't think saying you are gold is a proof whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

My 2 pennies.

I've seen AD thresh in non-ranked games and it isn't a success generally

1. Doesn't scale with the muplication of AD/AS/Crit/ArP like an "classic" ranged AD carry
2. Doesn't scale quite like an AD melee/bruiser
3. Can't go big tank *and* damage, like say Garen or Jarvan IV. He has to compromise
4. If he does go AD, he takes CS and/or kills from his lane partner = underfed ranged/melee AD
5. His Q bonus is magic damage and requires a delay between AA for maximum effect

So he may be able to hit *hard* but he can't hit *often*.
And what happens when his spells are on CD?

For me, his value is in the CC. Not his DPS

Comment: Thresh's basic attacks deal bonus magic damage on each hit. This value is equal to the total number of souls collected plus a percentage of his attack damage, based on the amount of time since his last attack. <-- His passive on death sentence, this means that he still does damage every attack, thus giving him some nice damage together with attack speed. If he goes AD he will usually go top and not steal any cs. If his spells are on CD, his main damage will still hurt.

Comment: you and marco leblanc, the only thing i could think of while reading this is you both sound the same. coincidence = nah

Comment: @ravekner look at my network profile. I've been here for years on the SE scene. Don't insult or cast aspersions because I disagree with you...

Comment: you posted an answer with the same exact thought process as marco leblanc, to a question that was never asked in the first place, and you expect me to care how long you've been in the community? oh wait, that sounds like something else i read recently, like how being a gold ranked player means that their answer is better than someone that isn't stroking their epeen.

Comment: @Ravekner: you really don't like dissent do you? Whatever. Deal with it: this is a public forum.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say yes.

Two reasons for this-

1) He has a ranged auto attack, so he would be capable of farming/harassing with a fair safety margin.

2) If played as an Attack Damage champion, he could fairly easily become a tough due to his passive giving Armor and Ability Power per each soul he collects.

---

Would I have him as the Attack Damage Carry? No.

Would I have him as a possible top lane champion? Absolutely.

He has a good kit and even though I still run into a lot of players that don't know what Thresh is capable of, that does not make him a bad champ. I currently see Thresh as **"the"** Utility Tough when it comes to team compositions.

He has ways to initiate, escape mechanisms for your team, and has a decent amount of Crowd Control as well.

So yeah, it is my belief that Thresh is absolutely viable as an AD champion. All you have to figure out is what items to build on him and in what order to level his skills as an AD champ.

Comment: I have to agree, it is totally possible i played him yesterday, starting out with Runaan's Hurricane , then went for a black cleaver. And by then I was blaasting people away.

Comment: Order of skills is focus his Q first, the chainpull. The passive adds damage equal to AD.

Comment: For any newer player reading this and thinking of going AD thresh competitively, please note:  Possible /= Viable.   If you play AD thresh in ranked a few times and get reported, you may get banned.

Comment: As user41604 states, yes, he is possible, no, he is not even close to viable.

Answer (score -1):

Hextech goes for spels not magical damage, be awesome on full ap thresh but ad no ways, blade of the ruined king however does work well

Answer (score -2):

Ad thresh is completely viable, so is ap thresh it just requires skill, I mean u got to know him off by heart also I play him with cooldown boots to keep cc up, thresh has to farm no 2 ways about it cuz he needs those souls to tank otherwise he is gonna get bursted,it would be a better game if u were in a pre-made team, and ad thresh can be an absolute 1 hit wonder cuz people so under estimate his attack range and when someone thinks they gonna get away and then they are bursted with 1 hit, it just require skill, and even if u don't farm a lot and u do get bursted your damage output puts the enemy team in a vulnerable spot

Answer (score -4):

Answers above our outdated, since the recent patches to thresh, he is a very viable AD carry, but Not doing physical damage, most of his damage is Magic damage. therefor "Is he viable botlane?" No, But he is very viable midlane, because of his hard cc He can counter Cait. and since he relies on basic attacks to do most of his damage, He counters Kassidan
But if you want to play a thresh mid, its extremely hard to learn, Its also hard to know how fast you can attack and poke them, Poking with Basic attacks will make their health bar crumble, And making sure your max your E first, because it has bonus damage from souls+AD 200% AD at max level, Make sure to build Sustain on him, Hextech gunblade is a great item on him, his magic damage will be turned into health and the extra sustain isn't bad Once you have about 200 AD and 150 AP you can start building tankyish, Really just health No more then two warmogs or 1250HP + is needed,